# IF statement dilemma

Tags: c#, xml

I'm creating a `.csv` report from a XML file that looks like this:

```
<Registration>
    <REGISTRATIONID>1</REGISTRATIONID>
    <TYPE>2</TYPE>
</Registration>
<Registration>
    <REGISTRATIONID>2</REGISTRATIONID>
    <TYPE>3</TYPE>
</Registration>
```

How can I get a string with the value "True", if in the XML file there is at least 1 `<TYPE>3</TYPE>` in the `<Registration>` tag, or "FALSE" if there are none.

For simply getting the value of each `<REGISTRATIONID>` I would do this

```
string type = "";

foreach (CGXML.RegistrationRow rr in fisier.Registration)
{
    type = rr.TYPE.ToString
    sout.WriteLine(string.Concat(new string[] { "\"", type, "\"" })); 
}
```

But sadly with my current skills I'm unable to make it work even for each
`<REGISTRATIONID>` an "TRUE/FALSE" statement...

So, the code for this, or where should I start reading to learn/understand this would be of immense help.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

First of all your xml is not valid. If you are posting a question you need to provide enough info so users can use the info to replicate your scenario.

Anyhow imagine this is your file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stuff>
    <Registration>
        <REGISTRATIONID>1</REGISTRATIONID>
        <TYPE>2</TYPE>
    </Registration>
    <Registration>
        <REGISTRATIONID>2</REGISTRATIONID>
        <TYPE>3</TYPE>
    </Registration>
</stuff>
```

Here is how you can read it. I am basing the true or false decision on the value of `TYPE` node. You may use the code to do it for another node. You can reduce the code using Linq but I kept it simple for clarity. Here is the method which will return a string containing "True" if any `TYPE` node has 2 or 3 in the entire file:

```
public static String SearchFile(string path)
{
    var document = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path));

    foreach (var thisRegistration in document.Element("stuff").Elements("Registration"))
    {
        var typeValue = thisRegistration.Element("TYPE").Value;
        if (typeValue == "2" ||
            typeValue == "3")
        {
            return "True";
        }
    }

    return "False";
}
```

Here is how to use the code:

```
var answer = SearchFile("PathToYourFile.xml"); // Replace with your filepath
Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", answer);
```

Comment: Equivalent linq version of SearchFile function should look similar to: `XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path)).Element("stuff").Elements("Registration").Select(e => e.Element("TYPE").Value).Any(type => type == "2" || type == "3") ? "True" : "False";`